# Bash bc calculator evaluation, multiple conditions with NOT evaluations

Tags: bash, bc

Long story short, is it possible to make bc evaluate the following expression?

```
echo "!(2.2 >= 0) && !(2.2 < 10)" | bc
bash: !: event not found
```

I know this works:

```
echo "(2.2 >= 0) && (2.2 < 10)" | bc
1
```

So what am I doing wrong? The bc man page said that it has support for *!expr*, but I cannot seem to invoke it. I know it's possible to work around the issue by negating the comparison signs, but I'd like to know how should the *!expr* be invoked in this case.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bash: !: event not found
```

There is a feature of `bash`, called "history expansion" (see `man bash`): it handles `!` specially, even within double quotes.

Replacing double quotes with single quotes should help (history expansion doesn't happen there).

Also, history expansion doesn't happen in non-interactive shells (that is, your example will work as is in a script).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the bash is interpreting your "!" as some kind of command. Replacing " for ' has worked for me.

It also happens when just outputing something to the terminal:

```
$ echo "!"
-bash: !: event not found
$ echo '!'
!
```

Answer (score 1):

a walk-around in bash with double quote:

```
kent@7pLaptop:/tmp$ echo  -e "\x21(3>5)"|bc
1
```

tested under:

```
kent@7pLaptop:/tmp$ bash -version|head -1
GNU bash, version 4.2.42(2)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: ASCII hex to prevent '!' evaluation? Interesting.

Comment: @S.T.A.L.K.E.R. I use this trick to avoid to escape ' or " when I wrote sed lines. \' \" pairs are annoying.